# Match the pattern only once, then move on to next pattern even if same pattern matches again in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to Match the pattern only once, then move on to next pattern even if same pattern matches again.

Source:

```
readMetaData(){
    if grep -q $1 $MetaDataFile
    then
        echo $1" Matched with Metadata Pattern, so calling HDFSWriter.jar"
        #java -jar HDFSWriter.jar $1
    else
        echo "ACK Filename not mactched with Metadata Pattern"
    fi
}
cd $ACKPath
FileList="ls -t *.ack"
fileList=`$FileList`
for f in $fileList
do
    FilePattern=`echo $f | cut -d '_' -f1-3`
    echo $f
    echo $FilePattern
    readMetaData $FilePattern
done
```

Files available in a folder:

```
ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE_9_2019092630009562.ack
ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE_10_2019092630009986.ack
IJK_VIEW_COB_9_2019092630009562.ack
IJK_VIEW_COB_10_2019092630009986.ack
XYZ_VIEW_MONTH_9_2019092630009562.ack
XYZ_VIEW_MONTH_10_2019092630009986.ack
```

Pattern to be matched with which is available in a '.csv' file:

```
ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE_<ROWCOUNT>_<CHECKER>_<TIMESTAMP>.ack
IJK_VIEW_COB_<ROWCOUNT>_<CHECKER>_<TIMESTAMP>.ack
XYZ_VIEW_MONTH_<ROWCOUNT>_<CHECKER>_<TIMESTAMP>.ack
```

Once the 'ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE' pattern matches then I don't want to go for the same pattern again.
I want to go for next pattern 'IJK_VIEW_COB' once this matches then I want to go to 'XYZ_VIEW_MONTH'
Even though the files are matching 2 times for each pattern.

I've done to match the pattern but it's still going to same pattern again since there is one more file with same pattern.

My current output:

```
ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE_10_1514120_2019092630009986.ack
ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE Matched with Metadata Pattern
ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE_9_1514120_2019092630009562.ack
ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE
ABC_PRODUCT_REFERENCE Matched with Metadata Pattern
```

Comment: grep has a -m flag to specify number of matches.

Comment: Are these patterns on the same line in your file, or in different records? If they are in different following close-together records, I would use `grep -m1 -A50 ...` to capture the next (eg) 50 lines and then grep that output for the other tags.